# In Java, why can I only restrict collection parameters using generics?

Tags: java, generics, methods

Below I have two generic methods. Both have two parameterized types T and V extends T.  The first method, foo, takes arguments of type T and V.  Strangely, I can call foo("hello", new Integer(10)) and it compiles and runs even though Integer clearly doesn't extend String.  The second method, bar, takes arguments of type List< T > and List< V >.  Here, I can not call bar, passing it a List of Strings and a List of Integers.  Why does the latter restrict the type, and the former not.

```
public class GenMeth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> s_list = new ArrayList<>();
        s_list.add("hello");

        List<Integer> i_list = new ArrayList<>();
        i_list.add(10);

        foo("hello", new Integer(10));  // will compile - why?

        bar(s_list, i_list);  // won't compile - understandable

    }

    public static <T,V extends T> void foo(T obj1, V obj2) {
            // do something
    }

    public static <T,V extends T> void bar(List<T> list1, List<V> list2) {
            // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Least specific type in `foo` is `Object`, equivalent code - change `s_list` to `List<Object> s_list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: When you call `foo("hello", new Integer(10));`, your method is known `<Object, Object>foo(Object t, Object e);`, you can see the restriction when call `<String, Integer>foo(String t, Integer e);`. Of cause, you now have the answer for `bar`.

Comment: @TrầnAnhNam, I think I see.  So when I call a generic method I need to specify the types just as if I were creating an instance of a generic class.  So for example, if I called foo using the following method call, I would get a compile error because the parameter constraints would not hold:  GenMeth.<String,Integer>foo("hello", new Integer(10))

Comment: For generic method, only need to specify before call method as I wrote in previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` will always be able to take two arguments of any reference type, because `T` and `V` can be chosen to be `Object`, and any reference type is a subtype of `Object`. So `foo` might as well be declared as `public static void foo(Object obj1, Object obj2)`; it would make no difference. The way it is declared, there is nothing that `foo` can do with either of its parameters except the things that can be done with `Object`, since the type variables are not bounded, so there is no reason for any restriction beyond that they are both `Object`.

`bar` is different because the type variable is in the type parameter. Generics are invariant -- `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>` (nor vice versa) even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`. So by having the first parameter be type `List<T>`, it forces `T` to match the type parameter of the passed argument *exactly*; i.e. by passing a `List<String>` as the first argument, it forces `T` to be `String`; it can't be `Object` or anything else -- it wouldn't be compatible. And since the type of the second parameter is `List<V>` and `V` extends `T`, it means the type parameter of the second argument must be `String` or a subtype of `String`. (p.s. `bar` can also be declared a little simpler as `public static <T> void bar(List<T> list1, List<? extends T> list2)`)